# How to Find the min and the max of diff

Tags: r

There is a data frame already given called taxis, now I have to do the following,but I am stuck on the last step...

**# Create my_distance and diff**

```
taxis_my_dist <- taxis  %>% 
  mutate(my_distance = hav_dist(pickup_longitude , pickup_latitude ,dropoff_longitude, dropoff_latitude ),
         diff = trip_distance-my_distance)
```

**# Find the min and the max of diff**

```
max(taxis[,diff])
min(diff)
```

Comment: Try `summarise()` https://suzan.rbind.io/2018/04/dplyr-tutorial-4/#summarising-data

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Answer (score 0):

## Create my_distance and diff

```
taxis_my_dist <- taxis  %>% 
  mutate(my_distance = hav_dist(pickup_longitude , pickup_latitude ,dropoff_longitude, dropoff_latitude ),
         diff = trip_distance-my_distance)
```

## Find the min and the max of diff

```
max(taxis_my_dist$diff)
min(taxis_my_dist$diff)
```

Answer (score -1):

Almost there!

```
library(dplyr)

taxis  %>% 
mutate(my_distance = hav_dist(pickup_longitude , pickup_latitude ,dropoff_longitude, dropoff_latitude ),
     diff = trip_distance-my_distance) %>%
summarise(
max = max(diff)
min = min(diff)    
)
```